Evaluating emacsclient code (emacs-everywhere) on Mac OS X
I'm on Mac OS X (Sonoma).
When I try running (from iTerm2):
emacsclient -e -c '(+ 3 2)'
I get the appropriate result (5).
But when I run
emacsclient -e -c '(emacs-everywhere)'
I get ERROR: Searching for program: No such file or directory, emacsclient
I have emacs server running and emacs-everywhere installed from MELPA.
Anyone perhaps have a suggestion on how to fix this?
